# point free where arguments are in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, pointfree, ramda.js

I want to write a function using Ramda's standard function set that given a dictionary and a key, it will increment the value for the key. Example

```
fn('foo', {}) // => {foo: 1}
fn('foo', {foo: 1}) // => {foo: 2}
```

I've gotten pretty close but am missing a way to curry properly.

I have a method that takes a key and an object and returns one more:

```
// count :: Any -> Number
var count = R.compose(R.inc, R.defaultTo(0))

// countProp :: String -> Object -> Number
var countProp = R.curry(R.compose(count, (R.prop(R.__))))

countProp('foo', {foo:1}) // 2
countProp('foo', {}) // 1
```

Now I want to return a new data structure

```
// accum :: String -> Object -> Object
var accum = R.curry(function(key, obj){
  return R.assoc(key, countProp(key, obj), obj)
})

accum('foo', {foo: 1}) // => {foo: 2}
```

But the issue is that in order to make this point free, I have to figure out how to get the values in the functions setup to get curried in the proper order. What am I doing wrong? Should I set up this function differently? I tried to set it up so both dependent functions would both take the key first, then the object, but I'm missing something. Should I be considering a specific Functor for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Doesn't your `accum` function work? Or do you really want to write `accum` pointfree?

Comment: sorry for the confusion @Bergi. yes, want to write accum pointfree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`R.lens`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens):

```
const fooLens = R.lens(R.prop('foo'), R.assoc('foo'));

fooLens.map(R.inc, {foo: 1, bar: 2});  // => {foo: 2, bar: 2}
fooLens.map(R.inc, {foo: 2, bar: 2});  // => {foo: 3, bar: 2}
fooLens.map(R.inc, {foo: 3, bar: 2});  // => {foo: 4, bar: 2}
```

Lenses make it possible to create a succession of values without undermining the integrity of a succeeded value by mutating it.

Comment: this is, well, exactly want I'm looking for. Thanks! I think i need to read up on lenses now, but this appears to be the Functor I'm after!

Comment: for those that might not understand how the `R.inc` value gets lifted onto the value. from the docs:
>  A map function is also attached to the returned function that takes a function to operate on the specified (get) property

Answer (score 5):

Several points:

**First**, if @davidchambers' solution does what you need, that's great.  It will be even better when the next version of Ramda is released and [lensProp](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/971/) is added, which will make this just

```
var fooLens = R.lensProp('foo');
fooLens.map(R.inc, {foo: 1, bar: 2});  // => {foo: 2, bar: 2}
```

**Second**, there is a difference between your original function and either lens version:

```
accum('foo', {bar: 1}); //=> {"bar":1,"foo":1}
fooLens.map(R.inc, {bar: 1}); //=> {"bar":1,"foo":null}
```

**Third**, regardless of all this, if you are interested in determining how to wrap your function up in a points-free manner, Ramda has several functions that will help.  There is one helper function [`nthArg`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#nthArg) which does nothing but return a function that return the nth argument of the outer function in which it's called.  Then there are several functions that act as extended versions of `compose` including [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge).

You can use them like this:

```
var accum = R.converge(R.assoc, R.nthArg(0), countProp, R.nthArg(1));
accum('foo', {foo: 1, bar: 2});  // => {foo: 2, bar: 2}
accum('foo', {bar: 2});  // => {foo: 1, bar: 2}
```

In this code, `converge` passes the arguments (`key` and `obj`) to each of the functions passed as parameters, except for the first one, then passes the results of each of those to the that first function.

---

**Finally**, although this shows a way to write this code points-free, and it's not in the end too horrible, it's arguably less clear than your earlier version that isn't points-free.  I love points-free code.  But sometimes we make a fetish of it, making code points-free for no good reason.  If you can't in the end use a `lens` version, you might want to think carefully whether a points-free solution is actually clearer than the alternative.

Comment: Hey @Scott Thanks so much for the insight. I already accepted but will upvote this, and suggest others do so as well. especially for the `nthArg` function which I overlooked. Most certainly this was academic curiosity more than a quest for production code. This did stem from a real code need, but I was able to use `R.countBy` because I didn't need to worry about a non-existent key for the counter. I appreciate the answer and the time it took to explain it.